# Como armazenar múltiplos checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou criando um sisteminha e como poderia armazenar vários checkbox e os inputs no mysql ?
eu sei que posso fazer desse jeito mas só se for pra uma coluna , no meu caso são quatros como poderia fazer

> if(!empty($_POST['genero']) && count($_POST['genero']) ){
>       $itens = implode(',', $_POST['genero']);

esse  é meu código

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "peixaria");
if($link->connect_errno){
     echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
     exit();
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $numero_mesa = $_POST['numero_mesa'];
    $pedido_refeicao = $_POST['pedido_refeicao'];
    $num_refeicao = $_POST['num_refeicao'];
    $pedido_bebida = $_POST['pedido_bebida'];
    $num_bebida = $_POST['num_bebida'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO mpedido(numero_mesa,pedido_refeicao,num_refeicao,pedido_bebida,num_bebida) VALUES('$numero_mesa','$pedido_refeicao','$num_refeicao','$pedido_bebida','$num_bebida')";
        $resultado_pedido = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

}
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<fieldset>
<div class="pedidos">
<form method="post" action="secao.php">
<table >
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" width="100">
         <span>Mesa</span>
         <input type="text" id="numero_mesa" name="numero_mesa">
         <label>
                    <span>Comanda:</span>

                </label>
                <br>
                <br>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="280" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Refeição</td>
    <td width="70" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Quantidade</td>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#1E90FF">Bebida</td>
    <td width="70" bgcolor="#1E90FF">Quantidade</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha">Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Fanta Laranja 1l">Fanta Laranja 1l</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha">Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Fanta Laranja 2l">Fanta Laranja 2l</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha">Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Cola Cola 1l">Cola Cola 1l</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Caldeirada de Tucunaré">Caldeirada de Tucunaré</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Cola Cola 2l">Cola Cola 2l</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão">Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Bare 2l">Bare 2l</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Escabeche de Pirarucu">Escabeche de Pirarucu</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Fanta Uva">Fanta Uva</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Escabeche de Tambaqui">Escabeche de Tambaqui</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Fanta Laranja">Fanta Laranja</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Escabeche de Tucunaré">Escabeche de Tucunaré</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Sprit">Sprit</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Tucunaré Frito">Tucunaré Frito</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Cola Cola">Cola Cola</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Sardinha Frita">Sardinha Frita</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Cola Cola zero">Cola Cola zero</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Jaraqui Frito">Jaraqui Frito</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Guaraná Antarctica">Guaraná Antarctica</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Pacu Frito">Pacu Frito</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Guaraná Baré">Guaraná Baré</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Filé de Pirarucu Frito">Filé de Pirarucu Frito</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Manga">Suco Manga</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Filé de Pirarucu a Milanesa">Filé de Pirarucu a Milanesa</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Pessego">Suco Pessego</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Guisado de Pirarucu">Guisado de Pirarucu</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Goiaba">Suco Goiaba</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="280"></td>
        <td width="70"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Uva">Suco Uva</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="280"></td>
        <td width="70"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Maracujá">Suco Maracujá</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="280"></td>
        <td width="70"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Laranja">Suco Laranja</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="280"></td>
        <td width="70"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Caju">Suco Caju</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="280"></td>
        <td width="70"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Agua Mineral">Agua Mineral</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="280"></td>
        <td width="70"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Agua com Gas">Agua com Gas</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="280"></td>
        <td width="70"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Cerveja em Lata">Cerveja em Lata</td>
        <td width="70"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="280"></td>
        <td width="70"></td>
        <td width="150"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Limonada Natural">Limonada Natural</td>
        <td width="5"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" width="100">
        <br>
         <button class="btn" type="submit">Fazer Pedido</button>  
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>


</div>

</fieldset>
   </form>
```

Comment: Cada `checkbox` deve possuir um `name` diferente, pode escolher um código para facilitar, na hora de salvar sugiro que salve em um campo só como um `array json` por exemplo, a quantidade pode funcionar da mesma maneira, dai na hora de puxar o pedido pode trazer somente os itens listados e as quantidades referidas.

Comment: Publica o trecho HTML do `input` checkbox

Comment: pois é cada checkbox tem name diferente , mais gostaria de saber como posso implementar eles em php

Comment: Estou um pouco confuso sobre o que você quer, mas é uma boa opção que o @MarceloBonifazio deu. Eu lhe sugeriria algo mais complexo, utilizando uma tabela para pedido, uma para refeições e outra para bebida e criar o relacionamento delas.

Answer (score 0):

Para esse exemplo utilizei `jQuery`, mas pode fazer em `javaScript` puro sem nenhum problema, caso precise eu te auxilio.

Diminui a quantidade de itens só para teste, alterei o valor dos elementos para um código do elemento, e o text com a quantidade adicionei o código no id para puxar a referencia do elemento correto.

Talvez te ajude a começar:

```js
function teste() {
  var inputs = [];
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { // Linha 1
    var verify = (this.checked ? 1 : 0); // linha 2
    if (verify) {
      inputs.push([$(this).val(),$("#"+this.value).val()]); // linha 3
    }
  });
  console.log(inputs);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" width="100">
      <span>Mesa</span>
      <input type="text" id="numero_mesa" name="numero_mesa">
      <label>
        <span>Comanda:</span>
      </label>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="teste()">Fazer Pedido</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="280" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Refeição</td>
      <td width="70" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Quantidade</td>
      <td width="150" bgcolor="#1E90FF">Bebida</td>
      <td width="70" bgcolor="#1E90FF">Quantidade</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="280">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="1_1">Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
      <td width="70">
        <input type="text" id="1_1" size="7">
      </td>
      <td width="150">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="2_1">Fanta Laranja 1l</td>
      <td width="70">
        <input type="text" id="2_1" size="7">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="280">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="1_2">Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</td>
      <td width="70">
        <input type="text" id="1_2" size="7">
      </td>
      <td width="150">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="2_2">Fanta Laranja 2l</td>
      <td width="70">
        <input type="text" id="2_2[]" size="7">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="280">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="1_3">Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
      <td width="70">
        <input type="text" id="1_3" size="7">
      </td>
      <td width="150">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="2_3">Cola Cola 1l</td>
      <td width="70">
        <input type="text" id="2_3" size="7">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="280">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="1_4">Caldeirada de Tucunaré</td>
      <td width="70">
        <input type="text" id="1_4" size="7">
      </td>
      <td width="150">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="2_4">Cola Cola 2l</td>
      <td width="70">
        <input type="text" id="2_4" size="7">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Explicando o código `js`

- *Linha 1*: Pego todos elementos `checkbox` que existem no formulário
  para fazer a checagem dos que estão ou não assinalados;
- *Linha 2*: verifico se o elemento esta checado, se estiver crio uma
  variável auxiliar que ira me ajudar a puxar o elemento;
- *Linha 3*: Insiro o código do elemento e o valor que existe no text com
  o id do elemento dentro do array criado antes da linha 1.

### Testando o código

Ao fazer um pedido ele te retorna um array mais ou menos assim:

```
[
  [
    "1_3",
    "5"
  ],
  [
    "2_4",
    "2"
  ]
]
```

Você pode imputar esse `array` do jeitinho que esta no seu banco de dados, ou então fazer um tratamento e criar tabelas relacionais que vinculem os dados dos elementos ao pedido, fica a sua escolha o que achar melhor e mais conveniente.

### Para enviar o pedido para o BD

Se estiver usando `jQuery` pode usar `$.ajax` assim <strike>(também existe um modo de fazer sem o uso de jQuery)</strike>:

Dentro da função `teste()`:

```js
function teste() {
  var inputs = [];
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { // Linha 1
    var verify = (this.checked ? 1 : 0); // linha 2
    if (verify) {
      inputs.push([$(this).val(), $("#" + this.value).val()]); // linha 3
    }
  });
  var data = {
    inputs
  };

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "secao.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(returnjson) {
      alert("processou");
    },
    error: function(returnjson) {
      alert("erro");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" width="100">
      <span>Mesa</span>
      <input type="text" id="numero_mesa" name="numero_mesa">
      <label>
        <span>Comanda:</span>
      </label>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="teste()">Fazer Pedido</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="280" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Refeição</td>
    <td width="70" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Quantidade</td>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#1E90FF">Bebida</td>
    <td width="70" bgcolor="#1E90FF">Quantidade</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="280">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="1_1">Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
    <td width="70">
      <input type="text" id="1_1" size="7">
    </td>
    <td width="150">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="2_1">Fanta Laranja 1l</td>
    <td width="70">
      <input type="text" id="2_1" size="7">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="280">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="1_2">Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</td>
    <td width="70">
      <input type="text" id="1_2" size="7">
    </td>
    <td width="150">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="2_2">Fanta Laranja 2l</td>
    <td width="70">
      <input type="text" id="2_2[]" size="7">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="280">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="1_3">Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
    <td width="70">
      <input type="text" id="1_3" size="7">
    </td>
    <td width="150">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="2_3">Cola Cola 1l</td>
    <td width="70">
      <input type="text" id="2_3" size="7">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="280">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="1_4">Caldeirada de Tucunaré</td>
    <td width="70">
      <input type="text" id="1_4" size="7">
    </td>
    <td width="150">
      <input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="2_4">Cola Cola 2l</td>
    <td width="70">
      <input type="text" id="2_4" size="7">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ele não está funcionando em localhost , tipo ele não faz o envio para o banco de dados .

Comment: Como você faz a chamada do PHP?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o código php

Comment: @allanaraujo você colocou exatamente o mesmo código....

Comment: o código php está no inicio e coloquei o seu código na minha aplicação mais ele nem faz o pedido e nem envia para o banco de dados .

Comment: @allanaraujo editei com um modo como pode enviar os dados pro php

Comment: Quando eu enviou ele vai mais não aparece nada no banco de dados só o id , os campos selecionado não aparece , como se estivesse vazios

Comment: da forma que eu tinha feito estava indo só ao invés de aparece os nomes dos pedidos e a quantidade ele aparecia somente escrito array no banco de dados .

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52083/discussion-between-marcelo-bonifazio-and-allan-araujo).

Comment: como eu poderia fazer a query para inserir esses dados no mysql ?